# vuex installation makes my project to go blank

Tags: vue.js, vuex

can anyone please help, i am doing this tutorial on Vuejs, everything was going great until when i installed Vuex and Vuex-router-sync then nothing is getting rendered on my browser anymore.
am using vue-cli2

Comment: Please provide a [complete, minimal and verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcv) example. Help us to help you.

Comment: This is the link to my code on github https://github.com/dngoyb/tab-track you can check the client folder

Comment: I suggest looking for an error message in the compiler or browser console. Without this, it is hard for us to help you. Providing links to GitHub projects does not help the community here. If there is someone with the same issue, we would like to see it on this domain, not Github. :)